# Rect not moving in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pong

I am trying to make a pong game in pygame. So I needed to make a rectangle controlled by player. I defined some variables for this purpose.

The variables

```
player = pygame.Rect(s_width - 10, s_height/2 - 35, 5, 70)
player_speed = 0
```

In the loop

```
player.y += player_speed

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if pygame.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player_speed += 5
        if pygame.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player_speed -= 5
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if pygame.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player_speed = 0
        if pygame.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player_speed = 0
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that draws `player` to the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just one problem in your code; you don't check

```
if pygame.key == pygame.K_...
```

You need to replace the `pygame.key` to `event.key`:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_...
```

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

s_width, s_height = 600, 600
wn = pygame.display.set_mode((s_width, s_height))

player = pygame.Rect(s_width - 10, s_height/2 - 35, 5, 70)
player_speed = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    player.y += player_speed
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_speed += 5
                print(player_speed)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_speed -= 5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_speed = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_speed = 0
    wn.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(wn, (255, 0, 0), player)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Output:

[image]